# Iterator over a list of pairs in C++?

Tags: c++, list, static, compiler-errors, iterator

I defined a list of pairs and wish to access them using an iterator, following [an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/).

```
class A{
private:
    list<pair<size_type,size_type> > l_edge_;   

public: 

void function() const{  
    list<pair<size_type,size_type> >::iterator Iter_;
    Iter_ = l_edge_.begin();
}
}
```

However, I got a compilation error. How can I fix it?

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'const iterator 
{aka const std::_List_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >}' and
          'std::list<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::const_iterator 
{aka std::_List_const_iterator<std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> >}')
```

Comment: first of all, you probably don't want to re-declare `l_edge_` in your function, because that will shadow the class member.

Comment: What is your compiler? [Seems to work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1s3lcB$4) on GCC 4.7.2. Is this your real code? Aren't you calling `cbegin()`?

Comment: I am using gcc48. I found that if I put list and iterator declaration inside the function, there is no error. If I put list declaration as a private member of the class, then there is error, regardless of where the iterator is declared.

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? Is it possible that `function` is in fact `const`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Fixed it; `function` is `const`.

Comment: @Pippi Next time, Pippi, please post your real code, instead of decided for yourself what is relevant or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to write a const member function, and not what you copied in the question:

```
void function() const
{
    Iter_ = l_edge_.begin();
}
```

Now, since the function is `const`, the `l_edge_` member is also const, and so, `begin()` returns a `const_iterator` instead of a plain `iterator`. But that hardly matters because the `Iter_` member is also const, so it cannot be assigned to.

Usually you do not want to declare iterators as member variables, unless very special needs. Instead, just declare a local one when you need it, and of the appropriate *constness*:

```
class A
{
private:
    list<pair<size_type,size_type> > l_edge_;
public: 
    //const member function
    void function() const
    {
        list< pair<size_type,size_type> >::const_iterator iter = l_edge_.begin();
    }

    //non-const member function
    void function()
    {
        list< pair<size_type,size_type> >::iterator iter = l_edge_.begin();
    }
};
```